# Allow an application to list the gitlab projects of the authenticated user (via OAuth2)

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, oauth, gitlab

I'm working on a project where I want to ask the users to authenticate via Gitlab(OAuth2). Then list the projects of that authenticated user.
any propositions for that flow?

Comment: Just ask the user to approve the request from your app to access their account based on the `read_api` scope. It's described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/oauth2.html).

Comment: just finished setting it up, Thank you for your comment